# Manually correcting gmapping?

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using a turtlebot in an office setting (cubicles/hallways create very few unique landmarks). My bot is attempting localization and placing itself in various incorrect areas. Is there a way to tell the bot where it roughly is within rviz? I tried using the 2D Pose Estimate but that doesn't work.

Thanks!
TaylorC

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35259/manually-correcting-gmapping?/) by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-05-30**:
Just to be clear, are you using gmapping, or amcl? gmapping performs both mapping and localization. If you already have a map, you should use amcl, which just does localization and can use the 2D pose estimate from rviz.

**Comment by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) on 2012-05-30**:
I am using gmapping and have yet to get a solid and accurate map.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-30**:
Ensure that your turtlebot odometry is correct before running gmapping. Have you already gone through this tutorial already: http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro?

**Comment by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) on 2012-05-30**:
I have calibrated it. I had to use rviz and manually calibrate it. The calibration program kept giving me higher and higher values. It maps unique rooms fine but has trouble with similar rooms. It will localize itself to a similar room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's not a capability the version of Gmapping in ROS currently supports.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0